# convert nginx reverse proxy config to apache

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

I have the following working nginx reverse proxy config

```
server {
  listen 192.168.100.7:443;
  server_name mysite.internal;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.100.8;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/mycert.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/mycert.key;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;
}
```

and I'm trying to convert it to run under apache httpd but I'm not able to get it working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Apache config for reverse proxy.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName www.yourdomain.com
    ErrorLog logs/yourdomain.com-error.log
    CustomLog logs/yourdomain.com-access.log common
     SSLEngine on
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```